# Scroll dynamically created ScrollView to end Java android

Tags: java, android-layout

If I have this void, which adds multiple RelativeLayouts into a single RelativeLayout (messages_container_view), which then gets added into a scrolling view (MessagesScrollingView), and I can see the messages, but the ScrollingView defaults to the top. I want it to default to the bottom of the scrolling view.

The scrolling view has been created dynamically.

I can see the scrolling view and the messages.

```
public void individualConversationMessages(final Context ctx){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Clear the screen
            MB.removeAllViews();

            //Set up the screen dimensions
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

            //This is where the individual conversation will get stored
            JSONArray ConversationMessages = new JSONArray();

            int container_id = 1;

            //The messages go in this container which goes in the scrollbox
            RelativeLayout messages_container_view = new RelativeLayout(ctx);

            try {
                //Get all conversations on the device
                JSONArray Conversations = new JSONArray(SharedPrefs(ctx).getString("conversations_array", ""));

                //Store only a single conversation
                ConversationMessages = Conversations.getJSONArray(ConversationID);

                //This is how many messages are in the conversation.
                int MessageCount = ConversationMessages.length();

                for(int i = 0;i<MessageCount;i++){
                    //Get the message we are displaying
                    JSONObject MessageData = ConversationMessages.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Message container
                    RelativeLayout MessageContainer = new RelativeLayout(ctx);

                    //Set all the messages in the conversation to read so that they no longer appear.
                    MessageData.put("read",1);

                    //This is where the message will be displayed
                    MessageContainer.setMinimumWidth(display.getWidth());

                    //This is the message information we will be displaying.
                    TextView message_text = new TextView(ctx);

                    //Set the message data
                    String body = "\n" + MessageData.getString("sent") + "\n" + MessageData.getString("message");
                    message_text.setText(body);

                    //Make those a nice easy to read size
                    message_text.setTextSize(13);

                    //Add the message text and sent time to the container
                    MessageContainer.addView(message_text);
                    MessageContainer.setMinimumHeight(message_text.getMeasuredHeight() + 20);

                    //Layout params
                    if(container_id != 0) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, container_id);
                        MessageContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }

                    container_id++;
                    MessageContainer.setId(container_id);

                    //Add the message container to the view of messages
                    messages_container_view.addView(MessageContainer);

                    //Save all the messages in this conversation to red status
                    SharedPrefs(ctx).edit().putString("conversations_array", Conversations.toString()).commit();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                TextView message = new TextView(ctx);
                message.setTextSize(15);
                message.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                message.setText("Error \n \n Something went wrong \n \n" + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
                MB.addView(message);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Add the messages into the scrolling view.
            ScrollView MessagesScrollingView = new ScrollView(MyMessages.this);
            MessagesScrollingView.addView(messages_container_view);
            MessagesScrollingView.scrollTo(0, MessagesScrollingView.getBottom());
            MB.addView(MessagesScrollingView);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to use `MessagesScrollingView.scrollTo(0, MessagesScrollingView.getBottom());`, but this has not worked. I have also tried to go to maxScrollAmount(), and that has not worked either.